# How to decrease the font size of 'References'?

Tags: fontsize

How to decrease the font size of 'References'? I want to make it 11pt fontsize.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-0.2\baselineskip}%
    \addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-0.2\baselineskip}%
}
\begin{document}
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \vspace*{79.4pt}
    \begingroup
    \fontsize{17}{0.7cm}\selectfont
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{\uppercase{TITLE OF ARTICLE     
        }}
    \end{flushleft}
\endgroup
\vspace{28.35pt}
\begin{adjustwidth}{25mm}{0mm}
\textbf{Name}\vspace{5.65pt}\\
Institution and adresses\\
\\
email \vspace{12pt}\\
\begingroup
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
\textbf{Abstract.} 
In this paper, we introduce about blablabla. 
\vspace{6pt}\\
\textbf{Keywords}: blablabla\vspace{10mm}
\endgroup
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
    
    \bibitem{yesyesyes}
    Author,
    \emph{Book title}.
    publisher, city,
    2nd Edition,
    2020.
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: Does the real bibliography of your document contain more than 99 entries? If it does not, you may want to change `\begin{thebibliography}{999}` to either `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` (if there are between 10 and 99 entries) or `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` (if there are fewer than 10 entries).

Comment: @Mico, there are fewer than 10 entries.

Comment: @MadyYuvi, I mean the title of "reference".

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It is a division heading, just as `\section` is and I believe that it should have the same impact on the reader as an unnumbered section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote,

> How to decrease the font size of 'References'? I want to make it 11pt fontsize.

I guess you want 11pt because that's the main document font size, right? If so, you may achieve your formatting goal by loading the `etoolbox` package and running the instruction

```
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\subsubsection*}{}{}
```

in the preamble.

By default, the header of the bibliography section in the `article` document class employs the instruction `\section*`, which creates an unnumbered section-level header which, in turn, employs the `\Large` relative font size. The command shown above tells LaTeX to use the `\subsubsection*` command instead, which will employ the `\normalsize` relative font size which, as you may have guessed by now, works out to be 11pt for the document at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} 'amsfonts' is loaded by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
%%\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% new:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\subsubsection*}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{References}        % use "\Large"
\subsection*{References}     % use "\large"
\subsubsection*{References}  % use "\normalsize"
\textbf{References} % <-- use "\normalize" by assumption
\bigskip\hrule

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    
\bibitem{yyy} A. Author, \emph{Book Title}. Publisher, City, 2nd ed., 2020.
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I want 11 pt because the main document font size is 11pt.

Thank you very much @Mico.