# How to decrease font size of 'References' using while using BibLatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, titles, fontsize, biber

I have almost the same question as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568749/how-to-decrease-the-font-size-of-references), except I am using BibLatex. I would like the size of 'References' to be the same size as the title of 'Problem 1' of the subsection in the document. I tried the suggested change in the linked question, but it did not work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{amsthm}
\usepackage[]{amssymb} %gives us the character \varnothing
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref} %lets us use links
\hypersetup{%
  bookmarksnumbered=true,%
  bookmarks=true,%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  filecolor=blue,%
  menucolor=blue,%
  urlcolor=blue,%
  pdfnewwindow=true} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\maketitle

\subsection*{Problem 1}

Blah blah blah blah.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an `article`-like class `biblatex`'s default bibliography heading uses `\section*`.

If you want a `\subsection*`, you can use

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

---

If you are not planning to use `\section`s at all, because their font size is too large for your liking, a better idea would be to make `\section`'s font size smaller. (Using `\subsection` as highest sectioning level can lead to weird side effects with section numbering.) See [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/35864) for help with that.